# Why is my image pushing my <td> so far to the right?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate the design and structure of a Facebook page post.

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
a {
    color: #365899;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.post td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.timestamp {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c34.34.431.431/s50x50/229746_457468357668297_1899772142_n.png?oh=a6c0ddb505a2485280d1661c1ee087df&oe=5916C9DF">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <strong><a>Toomblr</a></strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="timestamp">
                            <td>
                                20/01/2017 - 11:43
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Some content.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle of what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/6nodfbdj/

As you can see, the image is only 50x50, but it's pushing the `td` all the way out like that for no reason.

Somehow it's conflicting with the `td` that contains the content. So basically what's happening, is whatever the width of the content `td` is, is also being set for the `td` containing the image.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output you expect? The width of each cell in a column _stretches_ to the maximum width needed by the column (unless specified otherwise).

Comment: All the nth `td`s always take the width of the largest `td` in the group. Since the `td` with the image is at the same position as the one with text `Some content` it takes the with of that `td`

Comment: Better yet, don't use tables for layout -- use tables for tabular data

Comment: Don't you missing `<td colspan="2">
                 Some content.
                </td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, tables are not to be used for formatting. They are for tabular data.

From The w3.org site

> Tables should not be used purely as a means to layout document content as this may present problems when rendering to non-visual media. Additionally, when used with graphics, these tables may force users to scroll horizontally to view a table designed on a system with a larger display. To minimize these problems, authors should use style sheets to control layout rather than tables.
>
> Note. This specification includes more detailed information about tables in sections on
> https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#notes-tables

Instead you should use CSS. While the layout and sizes aren't exactly the same as your fiddle, take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/ringhidb/jeeu2yrt/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <style type="text/css">
        body {
          font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          font-size: 16px;
        }

a {
  color: #365899;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.post {
  position: absolute;
}

.header {}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: .1em;
}

.info {
  float: left;
  padding: .25em;
}

.site {
  font-size: 1.02em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.timestamp {
  font-size: .75em;
  color: #999;
}

.content {
  clear: both;
}

  </style>

 <title>CSS Layout</title>
 
</head>

<body>
  <div class="post">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c34.34.431.431/s50x50/229746_457468357668297_1899772142_n.png?oh=a6c0ddb505a2485280d1661c1ee087df&oe=5916C9DF">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <a class="site">Toomblr</a>

        <div class="timestamp">20/01/2017 - 11:43</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      Some content.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you want to do, but try this.

```
.post td {
    vertical-align:top;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: If you don't know what OP wants, why are you suggesting him to try this?

Answer (score 2):

It's being set by the width of the text in the `<td>` containing "Some content". Try:

```
<td colspan=2>
    Some content.
</td>
```

Comment: Tried that. It ends up setting the width for the content td as well.

Comment: Edited for something more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You had a "spare cell" what can be fixed with rowspan and colspan.
Try this:

```
<body>
<div class="post">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan=2>
                    <img src="https://scontent-lhr3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/c34.34.431.431/s50x50/229746_457468357668297_1899772142_n.png?oh=a6c0ddb505a2485280d1661c1ee087df&oe=5916C9DF">
                </td>
                <td>
                <strong><a>Toomblr</a></strong>
                </td>
                </tr>
                        <tr class="timestamp">
                            <td>
                                20/01/2017 - 11:43
                            </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2>
                    Some content.
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just an another small comment. You can easily debug the "spare cells" if you use <table border=1>

Answer (score 1):

have you tried image width 100% ?